# Computing Green's function in one dimension

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

### Computing one dimensional Green's function

I am trying to compute the Green's function for one dimensional Laplacian operator. The command I'm using is

`GreenFunction[Laplacian[u[x],x], u[x], x [Element] FullRegion[1], m]`

There is no result for this command.
 However when I'm using this command for the two dimensional case-

`GreenFunction[ Laplacian[ u[x, y], {x, y}], u[x, y], {x , y} [Element] FullRegion[2], {m, n}]`,

Mathematica is giving me the correct result. Can someone please help?

Comment: Cross-posted: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1328765 -- please see [this post](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1421/is-it-ok-to-post-both-on-mathematica-stackexchange-com-and-wolfram-community?noredirect=1&lq=1) and it's linked duplicate.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the concept of the Laplacian on the real line is ill-defined.

Comment: Look at the first example in the help to GreenFunction.

Comment: FWIW, the syntax for the Laplacian is `Laplacian[u[x], {x}]`, and for the region, it's `{x} \[Element] FullRegion[1]`.

Answer (score 2):

For a function in one variable, $\Delta u$ is equal to $u''$. So the second derivative of the hypothetical Green function $u$ would be zero everywhere but on a single point $m$ where the Dirac distribution $\delta_m$ is centered). So, $u$ has to be piecewise linear with a kink at the point $m$. Moreover, it has to satisfy $\lim_{x \to \infty} u(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x \to -\infty} u(x) = 0$. But that means that the piecewise constant slope of $u$ has to be $0$ and thus, $u$ is constantly $0$. Of course, it cannot satisfy $u'' = \delta_m$, which leads to a contradiction.

Summing up: The concept of a Green function for the Laplacian on the real line is ill-defined.

Comment: Green function is defined on the same region as the boundary value problem, so it should not have any conditions with infinity by default. In fact, it should satisfy the same boundary conditions as the solution itself.

Comment: @VsevolodA. My understanding is that OP is asking for Green's function on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: It's kinda worth mentioning that this only applies to infinite intervals. There is literally 1D example in documentation. GreenFunction[{-u''[x], u[0] == 0, u[1] == 0}, u[x], {x, 0, 1}, y]
Plot[Table[% /. {y -> i}, {i, 0, 1, 0.2}] // Evaluate, {x, 0, 1}]